# Randomize post (and page) IDs on generation

Tags: plugins, posts, filters, pages, hooks

I'd like to have my post (and ideally page) IDs being random (not sequential). Just like what [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/random-user-ids/) does, but for posts and pages - for an added layer of security (not that my tiny site needs it, but it seems like good practice). I've tried to look into the source code of the plugin, but it uses filters that are not applicable to posts and pages (as far as I can tell).

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: How do you think this will make your site more secure?

Comment: I'm with Q here... ...don't really see any benefit to this. The random user IDs is a bit different because what a malicious actor will do is always try to target UserID 1 (as that's usually the admin) and then they'll try 2, etc.

Comment: It's more conceptual than anything, my site is not really of interest to most of the world...but I heard that the main reason Parlor content was easily archived was b/c each thread was sequentially numbered and publicly queryable. So, one could issue a GET for a parameterized URL of the form ://some/base/url?id=N where N was an incrementing integer.

It was noted that "more secure" sites use GUIDs as IDs, so they are not "guessable."

When I read that, I thought two things: (1) cool; in this specific instance I'm glad and (2) huh, WP is the same way with IDs, and posts query-able by ID.